# Creating Docker image for a dotnet 6 application - Type '' already defines a member called '' with the same parameter types

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, docker-image, docker-build

I am trying to create a docker image for a .net 6 web api application, and whenever I run the command:

`~ sudo docker build -t aspnetapp .`

It shows me the following error:

```
/src/AmplifyAPI.Application/Controllers/Product/ProductController.cs(22,38): error CS0111: Type 'ProductController' already defines a member called 'SaveProduct' with the same parameter types [/src/AmplifyAPI.Application/AmplifyAPI.Application.csproj]
```

And that error is getting showed for every method of every controller. This is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "AmplifyAPI.Application/AmplifyAPI.Application.csproj" --disable-parallel
WORKDIR "/src/AmplifyAPI.Application"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "AmplifyAPI.Application.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR "/src/AmplifyAPI.Application"
RUN dotnet publish "AmplifyAPI.Application.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AmplifyAPI.Application.dll"]
```

And the application structure is:

```
--src
-----Dockerfile
-----AmplifyAPI.Data
-----AmplifyAPI.Domain
-----AmplifyAPI.Application
---------Controllers

--tests
-----AmplifyAPI.UnitTests
-----AmplifyAPI.IntegrationTests
```

Locally the application builds just fine. I am using Linux as operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copy the source code into the container twice, in different locations. You also both build and publish to /app, which might cause issues.

The normal Dockerfile for a .NET project first copies the .csproj file, then does a `restore` and then copies the rest of the code and builds, like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY AmplifyAPI.Application/AmplifyAPI.Application.csproj ./AmplifyAPI.Application/
COPY AmplifyAPI.Data/AmplifyAPI.Data.csproj ./AmplifyAPI.Data/
COPY AmplifyAPI.Domain/AmplifyAPI.Domain.csproj ./AmplifyAPI.Domain/
RUN dotnet restore "AmplifyAPI.Application/AmplifyAPI.Application.csproj" --disable-parallel
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "AmplifyAPI.Application/AmplifyAPI.Application.csproj" -c Release

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR "/src"
RUN dotnet publish "AmplifyAPI.Application/AmplifyAPI.Application.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AmplifyAPI.Application.dll"]
```